# Django Admin, showing related tables fields

Tags: django, django-admin

For the Admin interface in Django, I have a class called RideInfo set with attributes. I have another class called Rider that is related to RideInfo via foreign key. It is a 1 - Many relationship between RideInfo and Ride. Admin.py looks like the following:

```
from django.contrib.gis import admin
from django.contrib.gis.admin import OSMGeoAdmin
from models import Bike, RideInfo, Rider

class BikeInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = RideInfo
    extra = 0

class BikeAdmin(OSMGeoAdmin):
    inlines = [BikeInline]

admin.site.register(Bike,BikeAdmin)
```

How do I show the fields from Rider in the Admin interface?

models.py

import datetime
    from django.contrib.gis.db import models
    from django.utils import timezone

```
class Bike(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)  
    geom = models.PointField(srid=4326)
    latLonBoundingBox = models.CharField(max_length=50)  
    objects = models.GeoManager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class RideInfo(models.Model):
    rideSpots = models.ForeignKey(Bike)
    rideTypeMTB = models.CharField('Downhill/XC/Freeride', max_length=100)
    ridetime = models.DateTimeField('Ride Time')
    roadOrDirt = models.CharField('Road or Dirt', max_length=100)
    rideLevel = models.CharField('Ride Difficulty', max_length=100)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

class Rider(models.Model):
    rider = models.ForeignKey(RideInfo)
    riderRidingWhere = models.ForeignKey(Bike)
    riderName = models.CharField('Rider Name', max_length=100)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

# Auto-generated `LayerMapping` dictionary for bike_hud model
bike_hud_mapping = {
    'name' : 'Name',
    'geom' : 'POINT',
}
```

Comment: just register `Rider` with admin `admin.site.register(Rider)`

Comment: Do you want to show it in list or instance's form ?

Comment: @abhi i get the following error when I do that 'Bike.RideInfo' has no ForeignKey to 'Bike.Rider'.

Comment: @Zulu I would like Riders to be a list

Comment: inclde your models please...

Comment: @abhi I added my models, thanks for taking a look